# Is there any attributes for custom name of a class property?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any attributes for custom name of a class property?

I am now using reflection to get the property name.

```
        PropertyInfo[] propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i <= propInfos.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(propInfos[i].Name);
            .....

         }
```

But I want to have custom name of that. I don't want "Lastname" but "Last Name" in my result. I am not familiar with the asp.net attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Attribute Class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PropertyNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public PropertyNameAttribute(string name) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Decorate your Properties with that Attribute

```
[PropertyName("Last Name")]
public string LastName {get;set;}
```

With Reflection you can get those Properties this way:

```
var attr = (PropertyNameAttribute)propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyNameAttribute), false).Single();
```